# Why does my mandatory hashtable parameter not take my value

Tags: powershell

I have a function with parameters like this:

```
function foo {

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$foo,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [hashtable]$bar
    )

}
```

if i call it like this everything works fine:

```
foo -foo "abc" -bar @{"a"="b"}
```

but if I only call `foo` and PowerShell asks me to specify values for my mandatory parameters, it won't accept my hashtable.

```
PS C:\Users\abc> foo
cmdlet foo at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
foo: "abc"
bar: @{"a"="b"}
Cannot convert the "@{"a"="b"}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
```

why does PowerShell not take my specified value?

I also tried to write it different ways like `@{a=b}`, `"a"="b"`, `@{a=b;}`, `@{"a"="b";}` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mark a parameter as `Mandatory` and don't specify a value (argument) for it on invocation, PowerShell automatically prompts you for a value.

Unfortunately, this **automatic prompting mechanism for missing mandatory parameter values is *broken*** (it has never worked comprehensively, and still doesn't as of PowerShell v7.4):

- **You currently *cannot* interactively supply a value for any of the following types**:

  - `[hashtable]`,`[scriptblock]`, `[bool]`, `[switch]` (the latter two being uncommon as *mandatory* parameters) - their literal forms `@{ ... }`, `{ ... }` and `$true` / `$false` are simply not recognized.
  - There's also no way to interactively specify `$null`.
- Additionally, the automatic prompts, when they do work, are  *inconvenient* (no tab completion, no re-prompting on invalid input), and therefore currently of little use.
- These problems are being discussed in [GitHub issue #4068](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4068).

---

Given the above, it's **better to bypass the automatic prompts altogether and instead throw an error when no value was provided**:

```bash
function foo {

    Param(
        # Use a default value that throws an error.
        [string] $foo = $(Throw "Please pass a value for -foo."),

        # Use a default value that throws an error.
        [hashtable] $bar = $(Throw "Please pass a value for -bar.")
    )

}
```

Note that **`[Parameter(Mandatory)]` then mustn't be used**, as that would still trigger an automatic prompt, despite the presence of a default value.

- The - unfortunately unavoidable - consequence is that examining **the command's [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) will then *not* indicate that the parameter is mandatory**.

Comment: @mkelement0 Ok thank you for clarifying! I think I will use `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]` instead, which I always use when I feel `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` is buggy

Comment: @SimonS: But `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]` won't make your parameters mandatory, it will only complain if you explicitly pass an empty or `$null` value to them.

Answer (score 0):

Read-Host (which is invoked automatically when this happens) always returns strings. If you want to take hashtable input like that, you will need to process the input. I would do something like:

```
if ($foo -is [system.Collections.hashtable]) {
  //proceed
} else if ($foo -is [system.array]) {
  Foreach ($fooItem in $foo) {
    $myhash.add($key, $fooItem) 
  }
} else if ($foo -is [system.string]) {
  $fooItem = $foo.split(,)
  ...
} else { 
  //error
}
```

Comment: While it is true that the automatic prompting mechanism doesn't recognize hashtable literals, the only way to get the prompt to work is to _remove the type_ from the parameter (or to type it `[object]` or `[string]`), in which case you'll always get a `[string]` instance, so the (non-string) type conditionals in your tweaked code don't apply. In general I wouldn't attempt to hand-parse a _string_ value such as `'@{"a"="b"}'`; while `Invoke-Expression` would help, it's [better to avoid it in general](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).