# Emulate bash ls -ltr pipe grep in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I use the script below to to emulate bash

```
ls -ltr /www/root/*html| grep 'string' | grep 'narrower search string'
```

I open up the results in notepad - because it is so tough to cut and paste from the PowerShell terminal.

It works ok when there are two parameters - however it does not work well when I have just one parameter, like:

```
ls -ltr /www/root/*html| grep 'string'
```

I know how to use @ARGS in bash. However have not seen anything comparable in PowerShell. I don't see any kind of array to verify the line arguments in PowerShell.

```
param( 
[parameter()]
[string] $param1 = $null ,
[string] $param2 = $null 
)

$makecurrent = '(dir sample_file.txt).LastWriteTime = Get-Date'

$timestr = get-date -f 'MMddHHmmss'
get-childitem -path "C:\www\root\*html" -Name | sort LastWriteTime -descending | out-file -filepath "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt"
select-string -path "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt" -pattern "$param1" | out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt"
select-string -path "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt" -pattern "$param2" | out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$param2$timestr.txt"
$makecurrent | add-content -path "c:\temp\$param2$timestr.txt"
start "c:\temp\$param2$timestr.txt"
```

I am trying to get the PowerShell script to accept one or two parameters.

Comment: I assume you're `grep`'ing for the file name specifically?

Comment: A $null is not a string.  Instead of $null use an empty string ""  or  [system.string]::Empty

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i am grepping out al lthe *html files in the root directory. the second param 'param2' should narrow the search. I output it to text files for easing of cut and paste

Comment: This works when i have twp parameters  -- sometimes i only need one param - and that breaks this script - i use another script when i have just one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to use `@ARGS` in bash. However have not seen anything comparable in powershell. I don't see any kind of array to verify the line arguments in powershell.

PowerShell's **[automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)** is the equivalent of Bash's `$@` (`$*`) parameter: both contain the *individually* passed arguments *collected in an array*.

The main difference is:

- `$args` contains arguments *only* (and not also a first element that contains the script name or path as invoked, as in Bash, `${@:0:1}`)
- Therefore, it is `$args[0]` that contains the first argument (compare with `"${@:1:1}"`), `$args[1]` the second (compare with `"${@:2:1}"`), and so on.
- `$args.Count` contains the number of arguments passed (the equivalent of Bash's `$#`).

---

This implies that **you do not strictly *need* to *declare* parameters** (via a `param(...)` block), if you want to accept an unconstrained, open-ended number of arguments, which would simplify your script to:

```bash
# ... no param() block needed

# ...

# Simply pass $args - containing all arguments -
# directly to Select-String's -Pattern parameter
select-string -path "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt" -pattern $args | 
  out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt"
```

*Update*:

- It occurred to me later that by *chaining* `grep` calls you're looking for *conjunctive* logic, i.e. only lines that contain *all* patterns; by contrast, passing multiple patterns to a single [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) applies *disjunctive* logic, i.e. it finds lines that contain *any* of the patterns.
- Since this post is primarily about parameter declaration and handling, I won't fix this aspect, but I can point you to a `Select-StringAll` helper function, available from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/356acffc2521fdd338ef9d6daf41ef07), which provides the desired logic; you can install it directly with:

  ```bash
  irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/356acffc2521fdd338ef9d6daf41ef07/raw/Select-StringAll.ps1 | iex
  ```

  - I can personally assure that doing so is safe, but it's always a good idea to look at the source code first).
  - If you'd rather implement the logic yourself, see [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76220424/45375).

---

However, **you may *want* to declare parameters** for the following reasons:

- Use of *data types*:

  - Declared parameters can be declared as a specific .NET data type, such as `[int]` (`System.Int32`) or `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)), with PowerShell's parameter binder automatically enforcing that a given argument (value) is of that type or can be converted to it.
- Use of *named* arguments:

  - A declared parameter can be bound (passed an argument to) in a more self-describing manner, by preceding it with the parameter's name; e.g., if you define a parameter `$Pattern`, an argument `foo` can be passed to it as `-Pattern foo` instead of just `foo`, the latter being a *positional* argument, whose position relative to other such arguments determines what parameter it binds to.
- Robustness:

  - You can make parameters *mandatory*, i.e require that an argument be passed to them; if you don't, you'll get *prompted* for values, but note that the UX of this prompting feature is poor - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084372/45375) for a discussion and alternatives.
  - If you place a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute above your `param(...)` block or use at least one parameter-specific `[Parameter()]` attribute, your script or function implicitly becomes an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, in which case the parameter binder ensures that only arguments that bind to *declared* parameters can be passed.
  - Without it, arguments that cannot be bound to declared parameters are still supported, and collected in `$args` (which then contains *only* these so-called *unbound* arguments).

---

**PowerShell makes it easy to declare *array* parameters** - e.g. `[string[]] $Pattern` to declare an array of strings.

- By *default* they also require an *array* as their argument, meaning a *single* argument whose array elements are *separated with `,`* on invocation; e.g., to pass patterns `foo` and `bar`, you'd have to use
  `Pattern foo, bar` - note the required `,`
- To **get the equivalent behavior as with the automatic `$args` variable** - i.e. to collect *separate* arguments in an array, you can use a **`[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]` attribute** to decorate the target parameter, which automatically collects all *positional* arguments in that parameter, while allowing other parameters, if any, to be bound *by name*.
- You still have the option of binding such a parameter *by name*, in which case you again have to pass a *single array* as the argument, however.
- In other words: You can bind a `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter named, say, `-Pattern`, in one of two ways:

  - Named, with an array (note the `,`):

    ```bash
    Some-Command -Pattern foo, bar
    ```
  - Positional (unnamed), with individual arguments:

    ```bash
    Some-Command foo bar
    ```

Applied to your script:

```bash
param(
  # Declare -Pattern as an array of strings that can also
  # be bound with individual, positional arguments.
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
  [string[]] $Pattern
)

# ...

# Simply pass $Pattern - containing all patterns -
# directly to Select-String's -Pattern parameter
select-string -path "c:\temp\lsfile$timestr.txt" -pattern $Pattern | 
  out-file -filepath "c:\temp\$param1$timestr.txt"
```

While more complex than not declaring parameters, this form of your script has the following advantages:

- It enforces passing at least *one* pattern.
- It leaves you free to declare *additional* parameters, such as optional `[switch]` parameters (flags), say `-CaseSensitive`, which won't interfere with collecting the patterns via positional arguments.
- Through use of a `[Parameter()]` attribute, your script is now an *advanced* one, which provides automatic support for [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) such as `-Verbose` or `-OutVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

Array's are pretty simple in PowerShell - to declare a parameter as a string-array, type it `[string[]]`:

```
param(
  [string[]]$SearchTerms
)
```

Now you just need to repeat the string matching operation for each term supplied by the caller - we can use the `-match` operator against the relevant property rather than invoking `Select-String`:

```
param(
  [string[]]$SearchTerms
)

$items = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\www\root\*html" -Name |Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending

foreach($term in $SearchTerms){
  $items = $items |Where-Object { $_.Name -match $term }
}

return $items
```