# match command line arguments disable or enable only

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Not sure how to go about the following - the script will only accept the command line option of "enable" or "disable" anything else will result in the help message being displayed.

I am using this code below and would also like to show the help message if the command line args do not match "enable" or "disable".

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($args)) {
    write-host "You must use either enable or disable as a command line argument.`n`n`te.g. .\""$(Split-Path -leaf $PSCommandpath)"" disable"
} else {
    Write-Host "$osName $bit (Build $buildNumber) Release ID $displayVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your script an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, which allows you to declare parameters not only explicitly, but you can also make them:

- mandatory
- prevent passing of unexpected arguments
- control which parameters are positional (i.e. can be bound by values not preceded by the parameter *name*)

The [`[ValidateSet()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attribute allows you to constrain arguments to a given set of values:

```bash
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [ValidateSet('enable', 'disable')]
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
  $TargetState
)

"`$TargetState argument given: [$TargetState]"
```

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell* you must make do with the - somewhat verbose - *default* error message that is displayed if neither `enabled` or `disabled` is passed.
- In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use the optional `ErrorMessage` property for a *custom* error message; e.g.:

  ```bash
  [ValidateSet('enable', 'disable', ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not in set '{1}'")]
  ```
- Making a parameter *mandatory* means that PowerShell *prompts for a value* if none is given on invocation.

  - If you'd rather report an error in that case (given that UX of these prompts leaves much to be desired - see [GitHub issue #4068](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4068)), use a default value with a `$(throw "...")` subexpression - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084372/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (-not($args -in $("enable","disable"))) {
    write-host "You must use either enable or disable as a command line argument.`n`n`te.g. .\""$(Split-Path -leaf $PSCommandpath)"" disable"
} else {
    Write-Host "$osName $bit (Build $buildNumber) Release ID $displayVersion"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Better: `$args -notin 'enable', 'disable'`. While your answer technically works, it is better to work with PowerShell's parameter declarations, which offer a lot of declarative control over the desired behavior and integrate properly with PowerShell's error handling.